# Update field from different Model after storing data to another table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to ask for your assistance. I am not a hard coder person so I can't construct the proper code of doing this.

I have an order payment app that saves the payment for certain orders. There are no issues there. the data is being save in **ORDER_PAYMENTs** table.

in my create function I have this

```
public function create($order_id)
{

    $order = Orders::find($order_id);
    $order->company;
    $order->currency;
    $banks = Banks::all('name','acronym','id')->pluck('name','id')->all();
    $balance = Orderpayments::where('order_id', '=', $order_id)->sum('amount');
    // dd($balance);
    return view('orderPayments.create', compact('balance'))
               ->with('banks', $banks)
               ->with('order', $order);
}
```

the variable **$balance** do the computation of total amount then I will do the actual computation in `create.blade` to check if there's still a balance amount. here's what it looks like

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <span><strong>Remaining Balance</strong></span>
        <p class="text-danger">@php $remainingBalance = $order->grandtotal-$balance; @endphp
        {{ number_format($remainingBalance, 2) }}</p>                           
</div>
```

Now, what I want to do is to make a condition upon **STORING** the data (I am referring to STORE function) that if the payment covers all the remaining balance, it should update the column, **PAID** in **ORDERS** table. Here's the current look of my store function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'order_id'      => '',
            'company_id'    => '',
            'currency_id'   => '',
            'bank'          => '',
            'type'          => '',
            'payment_date'  => '',
            'amount'        => 'min:1',
            'rate'          => '',
            'bank'          => '',
            'page'          => '',
            'number'        => '',
            'booklet_number'=> '',
            'voucher_num'   => '',
            'notes'         => '',
            'user_id'       => ''
        ]);
        $orderpayments = Orderpayments::create($request->only(
            'order_id',
            'company_id',
            'currency_id',
            'bank',
            'type',
            'payment_date',
            'amount',
            'rate',
            'bank',
            'page',
            'number',
            'booklet_number',
            'voucher_num',
            'notes',
            'user_id'
        ));

        // NO IDEA ON HOW TO MAKE THE CONDITION PROPERLY
        // $balance = Orderpayments::where('order_id', '=', $order_id)->sum('amount');
        $order = Orders::all();
        // $paidOrder = $order->paid;

        dd($balance);
        // if ($balance < 1) {
        //     $amount = ;
        //     $item->save();
        // }

        if ($request){
            Session::flash('message','Purchase order was successfully added');
            Session::flash('m-class','alert-success');
        } else {
            Session::flash('message','Data is not saved');
            Session::flash('m-class','alert-danger');
            return redirect()->route('orders.index');
        }
        return redirect()->route('orders.index');
    }
```

At first, I am thinking to get the $balance variable from **CREATE** function since it is already has the computation then from there i'll check if the `$balance` is below 1 then if it is update the **PAID** column from **Orders table** to '1'

I am not a hard coder I only made this far because of the tutorials from everywhere and asking questions here. I can't find a proper tutorial to cover my problem. can you help me construct the logic that I want to achieve?

Thank you so much guys in advance!!!

**PROGRESS UPDATE**

I now have this

```
    // HERE'S THE PART THAT THE CONDITION IS PLACE
    //get the total amount paid
    $totalPaidAmount = Orderpayments::where('order_id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->sum('amount');
    //get the total order cost
    $orderGrandTotal = Orders::where('id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->get();
    //Set variable for grand total attribute Orders table
    $grandtotal = $orderGrandTotal->first()->grandtotal;
    //set variable for paid attribute in Orders table
     $paid = $orderGrandTotal->first()->paid;
    //Get the difference between  total order cost and total amount paid
    $totalBalance = $grandtotal - $totalPaidAmount;

    // dd($totalBalance);
    if ($totalBalance == 0) {
        $paid = 1;
        $paid->save();    
    }
```

My new problem is that when the balance reach 0, the condition I put should save the $paid = 1 right? instead I am having this error

[image]

currently that is my problem now. the saving part and the condition.

I hope you could help me guys. thanks in advance!!!

**SOLVED**

guys just in case you are get your self trap in this kind of situation, here's what I did it.

```
    // HERE'S THE PART THAT THE CONDITION IS PLACE
    //get the total amount paid
    $totalPaidAmount = Orderpayments::where('order_id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->sum('amount');
    //get the total order cost
    $orderGrandTotal = Orders::where('id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->get();
    //Set variable for grand total attribute Orders table
    $grandtotal = $orderGrandTotal->first()->grandtotal;

    //Get the difference between  total order cost and total amount paid
    $totalBalance = $grandtotal - $totalPaidAmount;

    if ($totalBalance < 1) {
        $setToPaid = \App\Orders::where('id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->first();
        $setToPaid->paid = 1;
        $setToPaid->save();
    }

    if ($request){
        Session::flash('message','Purchase order was successfully added');
        Session::flash('m-class','alert-success');
    } else {
        Session::flash('message','Data is not saved');
        Session::flash('m-class','alert-danger');
        return redirect()->route('orders.index');
    }
    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
```

[Learn more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates) Thanks @Marco for the tip!

Comment: You are assigning a integer to $paid and right bellow you try to call a method on it! Got it? What resides in $paid is not a object that you can call a method anymore. You need to do something similar to create, but actually an update to update paid to 1.

Comment: hi @Marco can you show me how?

Comment: Are you using Eloquent as ORM or what?

Comment: I am using Eloquent

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

```
 // HERE'S THE PART THAT THE CONDITION IS PLACE
//get the total amount paid
$totalPaidAmount = Orderpayments::where('order_id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->sum('amount');
//get the total order cost
//$orderGrandTotal = Orders::where('id', '=', $orderpayments->order_id)->get();
$orderGrandTotal = Orders::find($orderpayments->order_id);
//Set variable for grand total attribute Orders table
$grandtotal = $orderGrandTotal->grandtotal;
//set variable for paid attribute in Orders table
 $paid = $orderGrandTotal->paid;
//Get the difference between  total order cost and total amount paid
$totalBalance = $grandtotal - $totalPaidAmount;

// dd($totalBalance);
if ($totalBalance == 0) {
    $orderGrandTotal->paid = 1;
    $orderGrandTotal->save();    
}
```

I haven't tested but this is the direction you want need to go.

Comment: Hi @Marco it says "Method save does not exist."

Comment: Do a dd() on $orderGrandTotal, it should have o object representing the row from db. Try to read the documentation link i provided too. We are here to point you at the right direction, not code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: I did not mean to be harsh ok? I'm here to help but you mustr try some things and tell us what results you are having. :)

Comment: yup @Marco no worries :) Thanks again